# Calculate the overlap of a polygon with a raster map

Tags: r, terra

I am rather new with spatial data and I am not sure how to proceed with my code.
I have occurrence data from a lot of species and a .tif map with the occurrence of cocoa plantations in Ghana and Ivory Coast. I want to calculate the overlap of each (buffered) occurrence point with the distribution of cocoa.

Here is my map:

[image]

Here is a link for it: https://ufile.io/lnmqkkal

Here is a sample of my df:

```
sdm_data <- structure(list(scientificName = c("Centropus_leucogaster", "Charadrius_hiaticula", 
"Cinnyris_cupreus", "Milvus_migrans", "Indicator_minor", "Vanellus_senegallus", 
"Campethera_punctuligera", "Phylloscopus_trochilus", "Spermestes_cucullata", 
"Ceratogymna_atrata", "Columba_guinea", "Bubulcus_ibis", "Stiphrornis_erythrothorax", 
"Acrocephalus_schoenobaenus", "Prionops_plumatus", "Centropus_monachus", 
"Himantornis_haematopus", "Actitis_hypoleucos", "Deleornis_fraseri", 
"Corvus_albus", "Accipiter_tachiro", "Scopus_umbretta", "Thescelocichla_leucopleura", 
"Illadopsis_rufescens", "Columba_unicincta", "Ploceus_cucullatus", 
"Columba_livia", "Lybius_dubius", "Spermestes_cucullata", "Hylia_prasina", 
"Laniarius_barbarus", "Pandion_haliaetus", "Actophilornis_africanus", 
"Pycnonotus_barbatus", "Eidolon_helvum", "Spilopelia_senegalensis", 
"Criniger_calurus", "Tauraco_macrorhynchus", "Phoeniculus_purpureus", 
"Lamprotornis_caudatus", "Cyanomitra_olivacea", "Corythaeola_cristata", 
"Apaloderma_narina", "Lophoceros_nasutus", "Chrysococcyx_cupreus", 
"Uraeginthus_bengalus", "Pycnonotus_barbatus", "Vidua_macroura", 
"Ketupa_poensis", "Hybomys_trivirgatus", "Spermestes_cucullata", 
"Vidua_macroura", "Circus_aeruginosus", "Spilopelia_senegalensis", 
"Horizocerus_albocristatus", "Prinia_subflava", "Bubulcus_ibis", 
"Anthus_leucophrys", "Pholidornis_rushiae", "Necrosyrtes_monachus", 
"Apus_batesi", "Tricholaema_hirsuta", "Estrilda_melpoda", "Camaroptera_brachyura", 
"Streptopelia_semitorquata", "Passer_griseus", "Horizocerus_albocristatus", 
"Necrosyrtes_monachus", "Eremomela_pusilla", "Nicator_chloris", 
"Necrosyrtes_monachus", "Turtur_tympanistria", "Turtur_abyssinicus", 
"Apalis_nigriceps", "Criniger_olivaceus", "Gymnobucco_calvus", 
"Corvus_albus", "Buteo_auguralis", "Gypohierax_angolensis", "Pogoniulus_scolopaceus", 
"Chloropicus_pyrrhogaster", "Merops_gularis", "Estrilda_melpoda", 
"Passer_griseus", "Eurystomus_gularis", "Nigrita_canicapillus", 
"Stephanoaetus_coronatus", "Dryoscopus_gambensis", "Ceuthmochares_aereus", 
"Ploceus_brachypterus", "Ploceus_brachypterus", "Cypsiurus_parvus", 
"Apus_affinis", "Merops_pusillus", "Platysteira_blissetti", "Lagonosticta_larvata", 
"Pycnonotus_barbatus", "Chrysococcyx_caprius", "Eurillas_latirostris", 
"Sarothrura_pulchra"), class = c("Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Mammalia", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Mammalia", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves"
), countryCode = c("GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", 
"GH", "GH", "CI", "GH", "CI", "GH", "CI", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", 
"GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "CI", "GH", "CI", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", 
"CI", "GH", "GH", "GH", "CI", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", 
"GH", "CI", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", 
"GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "CI", "CI", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", 
"GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", 
"GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", 
"GH", "GH", "CI", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", "GH", 
"GH", "GH", "GH", "CI", "GH"), lat = c(5.294725, 5.538762, 5.069007, 
4.9631, 9.259442, 9.259442, 9.351597, 9.296375, 5.326462, 5.833334, 
10.686944, 5.354483, 5.244878, 5.2, 10.396633, 5.350061, 5.265666, 
5.375306, 6.229311, 5.935704, 5.350061, 9.296741, 5.85, 5.294725, 
5.416667, 5.282214, 5.4306, 10.396633, 6.239851, 5.330343, 9.400862, 
10.67723, 5.179573, 5.388454, 6.133333, 10.520621, 5.354316, 
6.241391, 5.61215, 5.589215, 6.241391, 5.85, 6.68671, 7.4145, 
6.241391, 9.259285, 5.935704, 9.281975, 5.216111, 5.77, 4.866574, 
9.249128, 6.767449, 5.265666, 5.4306, 5.199609, 5.362665, 5.38216, 
5.593093, 9.296375, 5.369245, 5.318909, 9.296375, 5.11396, 5.592857, 
6.180255, 5.4306, 5.582121, 9.296375, 5.32459, 5.885418, 5.350061, 
9.402673, 5.369245, 5.289211, 5.29904, 6.241391, 9.259442, 9.351597, 
6.241391, 5.354316, 5.350061, 9.402673, 5.32459, 6.68671, 5.354316, 
5.690694, 9.259442, 6.68671, 6.233479, 5.0854, 6.68671, 5.0506, 
9.296375, 5.34425, 9.416667, 5.0854, 5.406347, 5.85, 5.183314
), lon = c(-2.594147, -0.287876, -1.42497, -2.4084, -1.855252, 
-1.855252, -1.866111, -1.771631, -1.381812, -7.3, -0.806111, 
-3.988783, -2.640255, -3.733333, -2.062541, -1.38196, -2.581787, 
-1.629985, -0.527119, 0.093384, -1.38196, -1.850207, -7.383333, 
-2.594147, -7.3, -1.356295, -1.4145, -2.062541, 0.095351, -4.132249, 
-1.90428, -2.90983, -1.309481, -4.01923, -0.85, -0.362171, -1.383588, 
-0.553651, -0.190772, -0.181737, -0.553651, -7.383333, -1.34421, 
-1.8894, -0.553651, -1.855416, 0.093384, -1.86376, -2.651111, 
-0.22, -1.757812, -1.861067, 0.109927, -2.581787, -1.4145, -3.737939, 
-3.888946, -1.394263, -1.375694, -1.771631, -1.360245, -1.416425, 
-1.771631, -1.28007, -0.159177, -0.345341, -1.4145, -0.183042, 
-1.771631, -1.40445, 0.040941, -1.38196, -1.894798, -1.360245, 
-2.640378, -1.644067, -0.553651, -1.855252, -1.866111, -0.553651, 
-1.383588, -1.38196, -1.894798, -1.40445, -1.34421, -1.383588, 
-7.050476, -1.855252, -1.34421, 0.09053, -1.43393, -1.34421, 
-2.6949, -1.771631, -1.37552, -1.966667, -1.43393, -1.447472, 
-7.383333, -1.88866)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

And here is my code:

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(exactextractr)

#Read cocoa map
cocoa.map <- rast("cocoa_plantation_area.tif")

#Convert data to sf 
sdm_data_sf <- sdm_data %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84", agr="constant", remove=FALSE)

#convert sf object to  SpatVector for a faster buffering using terra:buffer
sdm_data <- vect(sdm_data_sf)

#Add a buffer of 100 meters
bufferpoints <- buffer(sdm_data, width=100)

#Match CRS of my map and my df 
crs(bufferpoints) <- crs(cocoa.map)

#crop the map to the extent of my buffered points
curr.map <- terra::crop(cocoa.map, terra::ext(bufferpoints))

#Convert SpatVector back to sf to be able to use exactextractr::exact_extract, because terra:extract is slower and my data set is big (555000 rows)
bufferpoints_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(bufferpoints)

#I think with this I am extracting the coverage of each point with the map? I am not sure
extract <- exactextractr::exact_extract(curr.map, bufferpoints_sf)
```

Now, the problem is that

1. I am not sure if I am doing the right thing in my last step using `exactextractr::exact_extract`
   What I get is a Large list with approx. the same amount of rows per entry, which does not make sense to me because each specie has a different number of entries. Maybe I am getting a value for each cocoa cell? And what should I do next with this huge list?
2. I need a coverage per point to be able to calculate at the end the total overlap of each species with the cocoa plantations.

I have tried multiple options throughout the day but I am not finding a solution. Converting my SpatVector back to sf seemed to be a ok-ish step because otherwise I was getting this warning all the time:

```
 Warning message:
In class(object) <- "environment" :
  Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object
```

Edit: Uploaded the map here: https://ufile.io/lnmqkkal

Comment: It is hard to help as long you do not provide data of occurences of cocoa plantations.

Comment: @Friede Thanks! I tried it before but it was too heavy. I uploaded it here now and hope it works: https://ufile.io/lnmqkkal

Comment: Please note that `crs(bufferpoints) <- crs(cocoa.map)` is dangerous unless you are certain that the data is in the same projection (coordinate space). You cannot transform data this way! If they are in different projections you just corrupted your data and nothing will work. Always manually check the CSR, for sf vectors `sf::st_csr(x)` and for SpatRasters `terra::csr(x)`. If they do not  match use `sf::st_transform` or `terra::project` to get into the desired projection. There are very few instances where piping a csr is appropriate.

Comment: For spatial type questions you may also want to be aware of StackExchange GIS https://gis.stackexchange.com/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with just terra

```
library(terra)
# create a SpatVector and buffer
v <- vect(as.data.frame(sdm_data), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
b <- buffer(v, width=100)

# replace NA with zeros in the cocoa data, that helps a lot later 
# save to a new file as it takes a while to process

cocoaraw <- rast("cocoa_plantation_area.tif")
cocoa <- subst(cocoaraw, NA, 0, filename="cocoa_area_01.tif")
```

Now extract and compute the mean value for each point. That avoids dealing with the list. Since the values are all zero or one, the mean  gives you the fraction of cocoa land within the buffer. If you have points that are on the beach you might want to set the ocean to `NA` (with mask) and use `na.rm=TRUE` to be more precise; but even if you had a few points like that, this would probably be pedantic in this case.

```
e1 <- extract(cocoa, b, mean)
head(e1)
#  ID plantation_area
#1  1               0
#2  2               0
#3  3               0
#4  4               0
#5  5               0
#6  6               0
```

And you can do the last step with exactexractr instead:

```
e2 <- exactextractr::exact_extract(cocoa, sf::st_as_sf(b), "mean")
```

(BTW: I am curious what the source of the cocoa data is)

Comment: This worked, but to be able to use `exactexractr` I have to convert the SpatVector to a sf object, and then at the end I get a Large list, and there I am not sure how to proceed. Otherwise it works with `extract` but it took me like 3 hours to run the code over all species. The data is from Kalischek et al 2022, DOI:10.48550/arXiv.2206.06119, and are available for download in the Google Earth Engine

Comment: You can do essentially the same thing with `exactexractr`. I have now added that.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I am not sure how to proceed with the Large list, which is the output of `exactexractr`... I tried calculating the mean of each point but the values I got were completely diferent from those with `terra::extract`

Comment: There is no list. Please have a look at my example.

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly on the right track. It is a matter of understanding the output of extracting pixels over a polygon area. One issue is that you are working with unprojected data so, area and distance are problematical since the projection units are degrees.

Here we first coerce the data to and sf object and project it to some relevant distance-based projection. I choose Chamberlin trimetric projection since we can orientate specifically to Africa. We use st_transform to transform the data. Please note that I edited your post because your structure object had an error so, while I was at it I created an object output (sdm_data), which is consistent with your code and used here as well.

```
# Chamberlin trimetric projection for Africa
ctp = "+proj=chamb +lat_1=22 +lon_1=0 +lat_2=22 +lon_2=45 +lat_3=-22 +lon_3=22.5 +datum=WGS84 +type=crs"

sdm <- st_as_sf(sdm_data, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs=4326, agr="constant")
  sdm <- st_transform(sdm, ctp)
```

Now, we can create some dummy binomial raster data (using the extent of the points).

```
cocoa.map <- rast(ext(sdm), resolution = 1000, crs=ctp)
  cocoa.map[] <- sample(c(0,1), ncell(cocoa.map), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9, 0.1)) 

plot(cocoa.map)
  plot(st_geometry(sdm), pch=20, cex=2, add=TRUE)
```

Since we now have distance units in our projected data we can specify an exact distance (eg., 5km) for our buffer. We then extract the pixels associated with our buffers. There really is no need to coerce as we can operate on sf objects and terra vector classes are not that much faster. We wrap extract in na.omit to drop NA's.

```
b.sdm <- st_buffer(sdm, 5000) 
e <- na.omit(extract(cocoa.map, b.sdm))
  head(e)
```

The results are a data.frame with an ID column, indicating the rowname of the source polygon, and a column containing the raster values (ie., 0, 1). Here we can get tricky and use lapply rather than a for loop. The do.call wrapper is simply to rbind results into a data.frame rather than a list. Then we can cbind the results back to the sdm points.

```
ids <- unique(e$ID)
prop <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(e$ID), \(i) {
  prop.table(table(factor(e[e$ID == i,][,2], levels=c("0","1"))))
}))
  prop <- data.frame(ids, prop)
    names(prop) <- c("IDS", "non-plantation", "plantation")
head(prop)

sdm <- cbind(sdm, prop)
  plot(cocoa.map)
    plot(sdm["plantation"], pch=20, cex=2, add=TRUE)
```

To break down what is happening in `lapply` first we have `e[e$ID == i,][,2],` which is querying the ID column (eg., i=1) and subsetting the raster value column, resulting in a vector within the given polygon. Then `factor` is used, with the `levels` argument, to ensure that we always have 0 and 1. If a value does not exist in the vector (say all zeros) then an empty level is created. When this is passed to `table` it will result in a 0 for the missing value. The `prop.table` function just returns everything in proportions rather than counts. THe use of `\(i)` is the same as `function(i)`.

Comment: Hi, I think you are mistaken about the need to project to use a planar CRS. That generally makes things *less* accurate due to distortion.

Comment: @RobertHijmans so when trying this code, do you recommend to leave the crs of both objects as it was at the beginning? Is the buffer of 100 still 100 meters or is it something else because I have to calculate it using the degrees of my projection? Thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Thanks! If I do this using `exact_extract` instead of `terra::extract` for it to run faster I get at the end a list with the amount of elements that I originally had in my sdm df. I think I get the value of each pixel for each buffered point? Do you know how can I extract this values at the end using the large list?

Comment: This solution is sadly not working out for me, first I got an error regarding the `na.omit`, afterwards I think the error was regarding that `b.sdm` is an `sf` object and not `SpatVector`. Here is the last warning: Error: [as,sf] coercion failed. You can try coercing via a Spatial* (sp) class

Comment: I would reccomend checking your R and package versions. The `extract` function now supports sf class objects.